# Why <input type="text"> has a less actual size than specified?

Tags: css, html, input

Consider a code:

```
<div style="width: 10em; float: left; padding: 0; margin: 0">
  <input type="text" style="width: 10em"/>
</div>
```

In fact, the text field does not occupy the entire parent DIV, as one would expect. Why? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is font-sizes.

em is a measurement of 'size relative to the current font-size'.

since the default font-size of an input element is smaller than a div (due to browser defaults) the 10em equates to a different width.

you can easily fix this by using '%' unit:

```
<input type="text" style="width:100%"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had such thought about the different fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a 100% width instead of an `em` width:

```
<div style="width: 10em; float: left; padding: 0; margin: 0">
  <input type="text" style="width: 100%"/>
</div>
```

Note that the text field will still have a padding and border - so a width of 100% will overflow the containing div.

Comment: Thank you. But in this case the <input> get a bit outside the parent DIV for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> problem </title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div style="width: 10em; float: left; padding: 0; margin: 0;background-color:red;">
  <input type="text" style="width: 100%; padding:0; margin:0"/>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```